# Rails Notifications of New Posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am developing a rails app where users can post, must like facebook. I want to implement a notification systems that alerts users to new posts. However, I am having trouble on how to tell if a user has viewed posts or not. I am literally clueless.

I am using devise gem which gives me access to certain user stats (if this helps):

```
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     :default => "", :null => false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          :default => 0
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "confirmation_token"
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
    t.integer  "failed_attempts",        :default => 0
    t.string   "unlock_token"
    t.datetime "locked_at"
    t.string   "authentication_token"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             :null => false
    t.string   "username",               :default => "", :null => false
    t.integer  "admin",                  :default => 0
  end
```

And my post model:

```
  create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.text     "content"
    t.datetime "created_at",                :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                :null => false
  end
```

How can I implement a system that knows if a user has seen a post or not?

Answer (score 3):

simple aproach would be like that:

create a model called **Seen**

```
rails g model Seen post:references user:references
```

**models/seen.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :post
```

**models/user.rb**

```
has_many :seens
has_many :seen_posts, through: :seens, source: :post
```

**models/post.rb**

```
has_many :seens
has_many :seen_users, through: :seens, source: :user
```

and you can create a method something like that

**models/post.rb**

```
def seen_by?(user)
  seen_user_ids.include?(user.id)
end
```

**controllers/posts_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  current_user.seen_posts << @post unless @post.seen_by?(current_user) 
end
```

Comment: If I poll this every minute or so, that gets pretty database intensive right? I have never done this, so I dont really know. But, I guess there is really no other way to keep track of posts the user has viewed.